# Maven builds but Intellij says cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a weird problem with my intelij. I am able to build my project by maven install successfully. When I want to run single unit test on intellij, intellij builds fails with error:

```
Error:(15, 20) cannot find symbol class B
```

When I open the class, no red lines, no errors. I tried to reload maven projects, cleaned and run install by maven but when it comes to running unit test by intellij, it fails. I check settings-> compile -> excludes and there is nothing there.

What  can be wrong here? Why intellij cannot build it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my test class, you can follow these step

- Right click on project then select new->directory.Create a new
  directory and name it "test".
- Right click on "test" folder then    select Mark Directory As->Test
  Sources Root
- Click on Navigate->Test->Create New Test Select Testing library
  Specify Class Name Select Member That's it.